# How can I have a date object with only dd-MM-yyyy format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

need date object (not the string) with only dd-MM-yyyy format. 
currently Kendo Grid filter provide effective_date as Mon Jun 10 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
I need to send this in odata Query as 
$filter: date(effective_date) eq 10-06-2019

(without quotes).

Can someone help me how to convert dates in dd-MM-yyyy format but keeping it as object.

Comment: You can't, an object doesn't have a format. If you want to format the date it means you want a string representation of this data, not an object

Comment: Thanks Mickael, You are damm right. now I need to see how kendo is expecting this in Grid Filters as part of odata query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use prototype for the date object and adding your own format like described in here `https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_date.asp`